# Sheldon Axler 7.35: Why is $R$ a positive operator

Tags: linear-algebra

> 7.35 Characterization of positive operators
>
> Let $T\in\mathcal{L}(V)$. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> ...
>
> (b) $T$ is self-adjoint and all the eigenvalues of $T$ are nonnegative;
>
> (c) $T$ has a positive square root;
>
> ...
>
> **Proof**
>
> ...
>
> Now suppose (b) holds, so that $T$ is self-adjoint and all the eigenvalues
> of $T$ are nonnegative. By the Spectral Theorem (7.24 and 7.29), there is
> an orthonormal basis $e_1,...,e_n$ of $V$ consisting of eigenvectors of $T$. Let $\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n$ be the eigenvalues of $T$ corresponding to $e_1,...,e_n$; thus each $\lambda_j$ is a nonnegative number. Let $R$ be the linear map from $V$ to $V$ such that
>
> $Re_j=\sqrt{\lambda_j}e_j$
>
> for $j=1,...,n$ (see 3.5). **Then R is a positive operator**, as you should verify. Furthermore, $R^2e_j=\lambda_je_j=Te_j$ for each $j$, which implies that $R^2=T$. Thus $R$ is a positive square root of $T$. Hence (c) holds.

I'm wondering why is $R$ a positive operator? I tried to verify it like this:

$\langle R_{c_1e_1+...+c_ne_n},{c_1e_1+...+c_ne_n}\rangle = \langle \sqrt{\lambda_1}c_1e_1+...+\sqrt{\lambda_n}c_ne_n, c_1e_1+...+c_ne_n\rangle=\sqrt{\lambda_1}\left|c_1\right|^2+...+\sqrt{\lambda_n}\left|c_n\right|^2$

But even if $\lambda_j$ is a positive number, $\sqrt{\lambda_j}$ still can be negative. isn't it? What did I miss?

Comment: Is $\sqrt2$ negative?

Comment: The notation $\sqrt{x}$, for positive $x$, by definition refers to the positive square root, not the negative square root. So no, $\sqrt{\lambda_j}$ cannot be negative. Even if the notation was ambiguous, which it isn't by convention, we would still just pick all the positive square roots to reach the desired conclusion.

Comment: Oh, yes, $\sqrt{\lambda_j}$ is the positive square root of $\lambda_j$, $-\sqrt{\lambda_j}$ is the  negative square root of $\lambda_j$ for the notation $\sqrt{x}$.